# Compile Poweramp widgets Android

Tags: android, compilation, widget

I am having trouble compiling widgets for Power-amp. I got a Template/Example pack. just like the one provided for normal skins (which works).

I downloaded the widget pack and tried to compile the provided example just like the skins using the command: ant dist.

But I ended up **getting an error**

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/****/Projects/Poweramp Skin/Widgets/Mad Jelly Widget Pack Test (copy)/build.xml:50: taskdef class com.android.ant.SetupTask cannot be found

Total time: 0 seconds
```

I read online that I must edit my build.xml for newer version of android-sdk or ant and switched the code out and replaced:

> < taskdef
>     name="setup"
>     classname="com.android.ant.SetupTask"
>     classpathref="android.antlibs" />

with

> < taskdef resource="anttasks.properties" classpathref="android.antlibs" />

It seemed to start working until I get **this error**:

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/****/Projects/Poweramp Skin/Widgets/Mad Jelly Widget Pack Test (copy)/build.xml:61: stylesheet /home/****/Projects/Poweramp Skin/Widgets/version.xsl  doesn't exist.

Total time: 4 seconds
```

The original and edited build.xml below

I tried looking around for version.xsl in the widget pack for it but didn't find it anywhere.

Anyways I am wondering if I am just doing it completely wrong or what I should be actually doing to be able to compile the widget example. The normal skin example compiled pretty easily, seen as nothing was actually missing.

If anyone has a experience with **Poweramp widgets** that would be great!
otherwise if there is another way to compile that would be nice, or how to get a version.xsl.

[My Build.xml (with small change)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14978403/StackOverflow/build.xml)

[Original Build.xml](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14978403/StackOverflow/build-org.xml)

Anyways hope someone knows what to do.
Thanks.

Comment: Please put code in the question and the exact error - also reduce the example to the smallest possible we cannot readlarge aounts of code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I finally found out the answer. The widget pack needed to be update to the latest ADK.
The Dev cleared it up for me later and updated it.